# Update / Refresh View while GWT RPC progressing

Tags: java, servlets, gwt, gwt-rpc, optaplanner

I have a requirement to update my view while my GWT application doing GWT RPC. Here is my case, I have to send some data to my GWT servlet, then in my servlet, I feed it to a server side component (optaplanner solver), and it will run for some time. This component have a event handler for every un-final result released. Now what I want is to get those un-final result and populate it in my view until the final result was released from the optaplanner solver component. These requirement very similar to upload file and track the progress. Please kindly give me your suggestions how to achieve this.
Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Have you tried using a server push technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Start a timer in your GWT code which will periodically ask the server "Do you have something for me?" The server may respond with null or with the intermediate results that you can show to your user.
2. Use a server-push technology.

The timer option is much simpler - it requires only a few lines of code and no external libraries. It is also a standard solution when the timing of an event is not critical (unlike games and some other applications).

Comment: Does the solution no. 1 has any drawbacks? I mean does it impact in the apps performance? About no. 2, I need to support some of users that still using IE8, which is not support HTML5 feature like server-push technology, any idea about this?

Comment: A timer with a simple request fired every few seconds will not affect the performance. Just make sure that the server responds quickly if the data is not ready.